# ORA-06512: at .MAX_MIN_HIST", line 37 ORA-06512: at line 1

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure MAX_min_hist
as
sql_stmt varchar2(4000);
sql_stmt2 varchar2(4000);
sql_stmt3 varchar2(4000);
var_date_of_trade hist_data.date_of_trade%type;
sql_stmt4 varchar2(4000);
cursor c1 is SELECT date_of_trade FROM hist_data where date_of_trade>TO_DATE('2015-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
begin
open c1;
Loop 
fetch c1 into var_date_of_trade;
sql_stmt3 := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HIST_DATA AS SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA  WHERE DATE_OF_TRADE < ' || var_date_of_trade;


sql_stmt := 'create table MAX_min_hist_data as ( select * from (
SELECT 
CODE,
((CLOSE_PRICE-"Worst")/nullif("Worst",0))*100 Upper_from_down,
(("Best"-CLOSE_PRICE)/nullif(CLOSE_PRICE,0))*100 Down_from_Best,
"Worst",
"Best",
Close_Price
 from (
SELECT 
DISTINCT
CODE,
MIN(close_price) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) "Worst",
MAX(close_price) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) "Best",
first_value(close_price) over (PARTITION BY CODE order by date_of_trade desc) CLOSE_PRICE
FROM V_HIST_DATA

)
)
)';
sql_stmt2 := ' drop table MAX_min_hist_data';
execute immediate sql_stmt3;
execute immediate sql_stmt2;
execute immediate sql_stmt;

end loop;
end;
/



exec MAX_min_hist
```

Execution of above code gives me the following errors-

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>   ORA-06512: at MAX_MIN_HIST", line 37
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

`DATE_OF_TRADE` is in 'YYYY-MM-DD' FORMAT .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
sql_stmt3 := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HIST_DATA AS SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA  WHERE DATE_OF_TRADE < ' || var_date_of_trade;
```

with this one:

```
sql_stmt3 := 
    'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_HIST_DATA AS ' 
   || 'SELECT * FROM HIST_DATA ' 
   || 'WHERE DATE_OF_TRADE < to_date( '''
   || to_char( var_date_of_trade, 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
   || ''', ''yyyy-mm-dd'' ) ';
```